# Should a service be both HTTP server and message bus event listener in microservice architecture

Tags: http, rabbitmq, microservices, backend

I am new to microservices and I am trying to found out how to achieve flexibility with this architecture when using message broker (let's assume it is RabbitMQ for example) as message bus.
Assume I have an `Account` service that allows to create/delete/update user accounts. Also I have a `Blog` service for managing user's posts in blog (create/delete/update again).
When user's account is deleted I want to delete user's posts as well (assuming posts and account infos are stored in separate databases). It means that `Account` service should push an event to event bus.

The question is how to handle this event?

I feel I misunderstand how and when should I use an event bus. How would you build an interaction between services in such case?

For example, if both services are HTTP servers then `Blog` service should be a hybrid application which listen events from the bus as well as HTTP requests? As I can see, not all server frameworks are build for something like this and there are not many examples of such applications in the Internet. Also I could run message bus event listener as separate process but it feels a little to complex for such task. Also I could split these services even more: handle all deletions in separate service, which will be an event listener only, thus all `get` requests handling remains in HTTP server.

Comment: There's gotta be some interface between the HTTP server and the message bus. Even if you decoupled it, say such that the message bus has its own HTTP interface which you could simply make an HTTP request to from your HTTP server… that just moves the "problem" around. Now the message bus service needs to be a "hybrid" HTTP/RMQ service. So, it really doesn't matter much. Having multiple interfaces per service is fine per se. Yes, not every off the shelf framework will be able to actually do this easily, that's correct.

Comment: @deceze, could I ask how would you redesign it? I just want to understand how such things are usually built. Or this case is unusual? I common words, I do not understand how to befriend HTTP endpoints and asynchronous events/messages. Feels like I'm missing something.

Comment: I've previously built something like that in Python using [autobahn](https://pypi.org/project/autobahn/) connecting to a [Crossbar](https://pypi.org/project/crossbar/) router, and simultaneously running a [Tornado](https://pypi.org/project/tornado/) web server, which is basically what you describe. They mixed just fine, running on Python asyncio.

Comment: I will say that you need to be really dedicated and follow the microservice mantra to a T, if you don't want to end up with merely a distributed monolith. The aforementioned Crossbar features RPC calls over the message bus, and as soon as you have RPC calls you basically don't have a microservice architecture anymore. I'm not a big fan of the microservice idea for most use cases, but there are probably use cases out there for which it is perfect. You just need to be really sure yours is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I could run message bus event listener as separate process but it feels a little to complex for such task

It is quite common for a microservice to have some background processing due to quite common approach of async communication via data buses or message queues and eventual consistency. It is up for debate how it is better to host such background processing - in the same app/process or as separate deployment unit. For example hosting them alongside with the API can be beneficial in terms of preventing partial deployment failure, but there other tools to handle that, on the other hand deploying processing as standalone component (from the same codebase/repository) can have benefits of more granular scaling and perfromance analysis. Personally I tend to go with the second approach, for example lately in k8s I try to create a deployment per service and the deployment contains several pods with different components for service (API, background processing, etc,)

> Also I could split these services even more: handle all deletions in separate service, which will be an event listener only, thus all get requests handling remains in HTTP server

Since the "microservice" term is not that strictly defined you can consider this component as a microservice, but since one of the main goals/tools of [microservice architecture](https://microservices.io/) is usually to have independently deployable
and loosely coupled components (microservices) and in this case those two are tightly coupled due to the need for at least of shared storage, I would argue that it should be (considered) a separate microservice.